# Use while loop to read value of rows in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop

I'm starting learning about looping. I have sample codes but sadly I can manipulate the while loop.

Need to read all value on column Status where i can sorted this in First A and to the Last B.

```
TABLE 

ID  Time                    Status      
12  2018-05-04 08:00:00     A
12  2018-05-04 09:00:00     A
12  2018-05-04 11:00:00     B
12  2018-05-04 13:00:00     A
12  2018-05-04 15:00:00     B
12  2018-05-04 18:00:00     B
```

I only way to do detect all value is to use while loop this is my sample codes

```
DECLARE  @rc tinyint

SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT


BEGIN 

WHILE (@rc <= 1)

BEGIN 

If (@in = 'A')

BEGIN

WITH Param As (Select * FROM Table WHERE Status='A')

SELECT MAX(Status) FROM Param 

END

END

END
```

[This image show the value should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlgeI.jpg)

```
OUTPUT

ID  Time                    Status
12  2018-05-04 08:00:00     A
12  2018-05-04 11:00:00     B
12  2018-05-04 13:00:00     A
12  2018-05-04 18:00:00     B
```

Can please help me ? Its really getting hard ti have infinite loop

Comment: is @rc returning you row count of table?

Comment: yes sir @AzeemHafeez . I want to check every row that handle A and B and display. If ever condition is true

Comment: Sir @AzeemHafeez Did my understanding in looping is right?

Comment: You have some missing code (where's the declaration of @in? what is before the @@ROWCOUNT?). To loop a set of rows you need a determined order, which you can't do by your supplied sample (you can't order by ID since all values are 12 and you can't order by Status since it will defeat your purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, using while loop will not be a good choice for these types of queries. It will be expensive.

You don't need a `while` loop to achieve this, it can be done in more simpler ways like using a `UNION` and `ROW_NUMBER()` like following.

```
SELECT Id,Status FROM
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN FROM [Table] WHERE Status='A'
 UNION
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN FROM [Table] WHERE Status='B'
)T ORDER BY RN
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ASPL72251)</kbd>**

**EDIT:**

As you have mentioned you have date column to order the data. For this scenario you can use `LAG` in SQL Server

```
SELECT Id,Status FROM
(
 SELECT *, LAG(Status) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) NextStatus FROM [TableName]
) T
WHERE Status <> NextStatus OR NextStatus IS NULL
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GCNHK33242)</kbd>**

**EDIT 2:** SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT Id,Status FROM
(
 SELECT *, 
 (
    SELECT TOP 1 Status FROM [TableName] t2 WHERE t2.[Date] < t.Date ORDER BY DATE desc  
 ) AS NextStatus
 FROM [TableName] t
) T
WHERE t.Status <> NextStatus OR NextStatus IS NULL
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QXCDS31876)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you sir to your help but I the flow is find first A and repeating value ignore and need find last B and B find First A .. thank you to response

Comment: Do you have any other column like id, date, because SQL server can return you date in any order and your logic will not work.

Comment: Yes sir I have datetime.

Comment: Can you update the sample data in your question with new date column. this will help

Comment: I also update my question sir. But sir the LAG function is not recognized. I use SQL Server 2005 and 2014

Comment: Updated for SQL 2005, please check

Comment: @Mina, did you checked the query, any further issue?

Comment: Wow Sir Thank you Very Much. It this procedure is making temporary data or table? I want to learn sir. Thank you very much

Comment: It is using a table vaiable, temporary table are little different and are created with #. Table variable are stored in memory where as temporary able are being stored in temp db, you can check google to find the difference and usage.

Comment: Thank you sir. Thank you very much 